# iOS Swift EXC_BAD_ACCESS code 2 SearchTextField (UITextField subclass)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, exc-bad-access, nszombie

I am relatively new to iOS development with Swift (I actually have 3 years of experience with Android development with Java, trying to learn a new technology). I am creating an app that requires the usage of a library known as SearchTextField:

https://github.com/apasccon/SearchTextField

In a shellnut, it's a UITextField subclass that has a dropdown suggestions/autocomplete functionality.

Below is the ViewController that uses it...

```
@IBOutlet var homeAddressTextField: SearchTextField!
@IBOutlet var workAddressTextField: SearchTextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    homeAddressTextField.delegate = self
    workAddressTextField.delegate = self

    homeAddressTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    workAddressTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

    //vvvvvvvvv EXC_BAD_ACCESS CODE 2 THROWN BELOW vvvvvvvv
    homeAddressTextField.filterStrings(["foo","bar"])
}
```

`homeAddressTextField` should be instantiated, otherwise any reference to it above should throw the same exception. When breakpointing into the problematic line, homeAddressTextField is **NOT nil**, and correctly shows that it is an instance of SearchTextField.

I have tried many things to fix or at least find the source of the error. As you can tell, I used a strong var instead of weak var for the Outlet.

I have tried using **zombies** to track any attempt to access a deallocated memory block, yet the zombie Instruments came up with no zombies accessed.

If it is worth noting, the error disappears as soon as the problematic line containing filterStrings() is removed. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you please post the whole error here?

Comment: Are you using ARC?

Comment: @SivajeeBattina Not sure what you mean by "the whole error", since this is what I'm getting... `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x610000472680)` on the line indicated by the question. The address of the exception changes w/ every run.

Comment: @Balasubramanian Turns out I didn't know what I was saying and I'm **not** using ARC. I'll edit accordingly

Comment: @Balasubramanian Sorry, I meant I didn't change anything to do with ARC since the project was created, and I believe ARC is automatically enabled. If that is so, I believe I am using ARC.

Comment: can you check here https://github.com/apasccon/SearchTextField/issues/48

Comment: Oh wow @karthikeyan I feel like an idiot now. If you post that in answer form I'll mark it as correct answer; thank you!

Comment: @darkterbears, i updated as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems bug in library, could you please check here

[SearchTextField Issue](https://github.com/apasccon/SearchTextField/issues/48)

It is in still open issues at their repository.

Kindly watch issues in repository, if you try to use someone readymade code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've attached your IBOutlet in interface builder?

Try putting a breakpoint on the line that's crashing. That will stop it right before executing that line. Then, in the console (command+shift+y) you'll see a line that says "lldb" - put your cursor there and type `po homeAddressTextField` and see if it returns a value, or nil. If nil, then the IBOutlet is not set properly, which would cause bad access.

Additionally, if it *is* indeed nil, you'll want to make sure that the subclass and module are both set within interface builder on the SearchTextField, as well as making sure to set the outlet itself. You can also try filtering these strings in the viewDidAppear() method just to see if it is indeed an issue with the reference to the SearchTextField.

Edit: I've looked through the code a bit of the repo. You might not want to set the datasource and delegate properties, as the SearchTextField has a datasource and delegate of its own. You simply need to set the filterable strings as you are on the last line. So try removing the calls to make the view controller the datasource/delegate.

Comment: homeAddressTextField is NOT nil, as confirmed by lldb as well as the debugger interface.

Comment: Just updated my answer. Try removing the delegate lines.

Comment: I tried removing the delegate lines as well as the UITextFieldDelegate from the class declaration. It still threw the exception. In fact, I added the delegate lines in an attempt to fix it lol

Comment: Any way you can post the stack trace? It should show up in the console when your app crashes.

Comment: @darkterbears this is the kind of question where you're not giving us enough information to reproduce the issue. Perhaps sharing the entire project file would be a good idea...

Comment: There does not seem to be any sort of stack trace in the console (I've seen one before and I know what they look like). I did print the debugDescription of the textfield right before it crashed, and here it is: `<UITextField: 0x7fef3bb3bee0; frame = (48 318.5; 279 30); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6180000295a0>>`

Comment: @Honey I am required to maintain as much confidentiality as possible for this project, sorry about that. You should be able to attempt to reproduce it if you create a new project and use the SearchTextField library.

Comment: @darkterbears That's not how stackoverflow works. To ask a good question, it's [your responsibility to give us something reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (See where it says **Help others reproduce the problem**). Perhaps copy/paste the pod into a project and then see if the issue persists. Additionally I downloaded the project Sample. It works using their own code. So not sure what I need to test. But again regardless of that, give us something we can reproduce, don't let others do your work.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the textField and then adding class name = SearchTextField.swift worked for me.

[image]